# Overlay image in Angular using Bootstrap

Tags: css

I am new to web development and am using `Angular` with `Bootstrap` to develop a practice project. I want to have a header component and in my `app.component` I am calling the header component. Now In the `app.component`, I want to have a background image which covers around 50% of the screen including the header.  I have tried implementing this, but somehow it is appearing to be wrong. There are couple of issues I am facing.

1) When I scroll down, it looks odd and appears as if the bottom portion of page goes on top of the image.

2) The image is not getting shown in full. Here is  my image, if you look in my implementation, the entire image is not getting displayed.

[image]

Here is the `Stack blitz` link to [My work](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3g5ahp).

Please view the demo in full screen: [Demo Url](https://angular-3g5ahp.stackblitz.io/#)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the problem with the css (*app.component.css*) in 2 rules:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

> determines whether that image's position is fixed within the viewport, or scrolls along with its containing block.

<sup>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment</sup>

So I removed it.

Also:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Which stretch the image to full width / height. In your case, I guess you want that it will take only the full width so the way to do this is:

```
background-size: 100% auto;
```

The result is:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rbtcs9?file=src/app/app.component.css

Let me know if it that you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, I have one more doubt, if I don't want to move the content behind the header on scroll, what changes should I make. It is similar to Stack overflow website(https://stackoverflow.com/ ). If you see in this website on scrolling down content do not go on top of the header.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. When I scroll, the header is scrolling as well and the content goes behind the header: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rROkr.png

Comment: I am sorry, I understood, it was just the opacity effect. I had opacity set to 0.7 in header and that is why the content was visible on top of the header on scrolling. Thanks a lot.

Comment: My pleasure   Good luck 